# Are levels of measurement and measurement scales the same thing?

Tags: multivariate-analysis

My text book defines levels of measurement and measurement scales as the same thing. They can be divided in:

- Categorical

  - Nominal
  - Ordinal
- Numerical

  - Interval
  - Ratio

Are they actually the same?

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users. They are used interchangeably in some textbooks. The term "scale" sometimes refer to psychometric scales (e.g., Likert scale). Unfortunately, there are many terms which mean different things in different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Terminology is not always handled consistently in different literature. I'd say (and have seen in some literature) that levels of measurement refer to what you list, whereas a scale of measurement refers to a specific scale in a specific application. Some may however use the term in the way you suggest.